# How to get the string value of a parameter in Java?

Tags: java, parameters

I'm trying to save a parameter as a property, the parameter is : `testSpeed ( = "20" )`, and I have a method :

```
saveProperty(String Parameter)
```

which will save the value of Parameter to a file, something like this :

```
saveProperty(testSpeed);
```

My property file looks like this :

```
testSpeed : 20
testHeight : 300
```

My question is : In Java is it possible to get the name of the parameter, in this case the parameter passed to `saveProperty()` is `testSpeed`, and it's name is `"testSpeed"`, how to get this string from inside of `saveProperty()`, so I don't have to do the following to save it :

```
saveProperty(String Name,String Value);
```

and call it like this :

```
saveProperty("testSpeed",testSpeed)
```

Also, when I need to get it out from the property file, I can call :

```
getProperty(testSpeed)
```

I know how to use a property file, I'm just using it as an example, maybe it caused some confusion when I mentioned property file.

The essence of the question is : how to get the name of a parameter passed into a method.

```
void someMethod(String Parameter_XYZ)
{
  // In here if I call someMethod(testSpeed), how to get the string "testSpeed", 
  // not it's value, but it's name, 
  // exactly spelled as "testSpeed" ?
}
```

Is this doable in Java ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all correct format of property file is this:

```
testSpeed=20
testHeight=300
```

Now to pull any property from this you need to pass key name, which you're already doing in `saveProperty(String name, String value)` method. However if I understood your question correctly then you want to avoid passing property name. You can have some custom methods like this:

```
void saveTestSpeed(String value) {
    saveProperty("testSpeed", value);
}

Strig getTestSpeed() {
    getProperty("testSpeed");
}
```

**EDIT:** Based on your edited question.

**No it is not possible in Java.**

Please remember that **Java is strictly pass-by-value** that makes it impossible to figure out the name of actual variable name at callee's end. Inside the `saveProperty` method we can only get the value of the arguments since in Java Object references are passed by value not by name.

This is not practical also since there is nothing that stops method being called like:

```
savePropery( "20" );
```

In the case what should be the name of the property?

Comment: You need to have separate getter/setter for `testHeigh` (this is of course not recommended for property file with 100 properties)

Comment: @Alya'aGamal: How will use of regex help here?

Comment: @Alya'aGamal: I think that was just an example to illustrate the value of testSpeed. OP wants to use this code: **`testSpeed=20; saveProperty(testSpeed);`**

Answer (score 1):

Use [Properties](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Properties.html):

```
public class Util
{
    private static final Properties prop = new Properties();

    static
    {
        try
        {
            prop.load(new FileReader(new File("prop.txt")));
        }
        catch(IOException e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public static void setProperty(String key, String value)
    {
        prop.setProperty(key, value);
        persistCurrentProperites();
    }

    public static String getProperty(String key)
    {
        return prop.getProperty(key);
    }

    private static void persistCurrentProperites()
    {
        try
        {
            prop.store(new FileWriter(new File("prop.txt")), null);
        }
        catch(IOException e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest maintaining the key-value pairs to acheive a more generic solution. You can use [`Properties`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Properties.html)

```
void saveProperty(String key, String value) {

    properties.setProperty(key, value);
}
```

use `getProperty` to retrieve

```
properties.getProperty(key)
```